# Accessing an argument in a route controller after changing routes programmatically

Tags: meteor, iron-router

The [iron-router documentation describes changing routes programmatically](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/dev/DOCS.md#changing-routes-programmatically). The example shows how to pass an argument but I am having trouble accessing this argument in a route controller extension.

In the code below, how would I access the `'baz'` value in my `waitOn` function?

***routes.js***

```
Router.configure({
  loadingTemplate: 'Loading',
  notFoundTemplate: 'NotFound',
  templateNameConverter: 'upperCamelCase',
  routeControllerNameConverter: 'upperCamelCase',
  onBeforeAction: 'loading'
});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('foo', {
    path: '/',
    action: function() {
      Router.go('bar',{_id: 'baz'});
    }
  });

  this.route('bar');
});
```

***bar.js***

```
BarController = RouteController.extend({
  waitOn: function() {
    // this.params._id does not work
    // this._id does not work
    // do work and return something;
  },
  data: function() {
    // fetch and return something;
  },
  action: function() {
    this.render();
  }
});
```

**Clarification**: I would like to achieve this without including the parameter in a dynamic path segment. I just want to pass an argument like any other JavaScript function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the param in your path variable

E.g for your `foo` path if you used

```
path: '/:_id'
```

instead of

```
path : '/'
```

The addition of `:_id` is a placeholder for something such as `baz` to be available with the  `this.params` object.

Then the value would be available with `this.params._id`, your URL would also change to `/baz`.

Comment: I understand dynamic path segments and I realize that this is what is being done in the documentation example. Can I not simply pass an argument without it being a part of the path?

Comment: @MicahAlcorn it would be defeating a purpose of the router. If you want to have variables without it being in the path you might be better of using `Session.set` and `Session.get` instead: http://docs.meteor.com/#session_get